# Free actions of the circle on itself

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions

My question might be a silly one. I think that the only free action of $S^1$ (thought as a lie group) on itself  (up to equivariant diffeomorphisms) is the complex multiplication, but I don't know how to prove/disprove this. Am I correct?

Comment: I think you can make the standard action non-smooth, so really you're asking for "up to equivariant homeomorphisms". And maybe your claim then follows from the fact that the orbit $S^1 \cdot 1 \subset S^1$ has to be $S^1$ by the classification of $1$-dimensional topological manifolds. But I don't know much about these things, so it might be a bad way to think of it.